# Issue with Tomcat application url

Tags: tomcat, rewrite, url, deployment

At domain `my.test.org` I have the following setup:

- A Tomcat6 running on port 8080
- A redirection from port 80 to 8080 at the OS level (using NAT)
- An application deployed in Tomcat at `http://my.test.org/myapp` (the [Pubby](http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/pubby/) app, a semantic web front-end).

The issue is that the correct URL for `myapp` should be 
`http://my.test.org/prefix/myapp`: the app publishes linked data having `http://my.test.org/prefix/myapp` as prefix. For this reason it won't work at `http://my.test.org/myapp`. In other words, I need to re-write the URL in a transparent way, without redirections.

I tried to deploy the app in a subfolder in `webapps` (locally `$CATALINA/webapps/prefix/myapp`) with no luck.

What would be a good solution to deploy the app at `http://my.test.org/prefix/myapp`?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Can you clarify why there's a prefix outside the application namespace?  The info I'm seeing in the docs has the optional prefixes within the webapp namespace.

Comment: Yes, but those options don't seem to work. It's because the RDF dataset I want to publish has a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

With tomcat you can override the prefix an app is deployed to. See the manager interface just above the upload war section, there are ~4 fields to fill in from memory.

---

I can't comment here yet so replying in the answer.

You may need to edit the tomcat-users.xml to add a manager role (there are comments in the file to assist) and also add a user with the manager role assigned.

Once you've done that, you should be able to access the /manager/ uri and on that screen you'll see the section I'm t
Referring to.

Comment: Thanks! I installed the tomcat-admin package, but I can't access it. What file/interface you are talking about?